# Simple (?) augmented reality app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I need to develop an iOS app that implements this simple (I hope) functionality: fire up camera mode, let the user (who's standing in a well known point in a room) point a marker in a room, then adding some AR info localized within the room.

For instance, I stand at the entry door of my lab, I point a marker on the opposite wall (in order to fine calibrate my iPhone's position), I start moving the phone to point different zones of the room and AR info panels appear showing where tools in the lab are (of course i'm assuming I already have some location based inventory data of the tools in the room).

I'm totally new to AR so I'd just need some (not completely general) startup tips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ARKit](https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/) is the one you have to refer.